ES Lint import/order rule not respecting charset order
My ESLint import/order rule is behaving abnormally. It used to work fine before but I have recently run some package upgrades on my application and the alphabetize property is arranging my import statements in the wrong order.
This is my eslint config:
  "import/order": ["error", {
            "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal"],
            "alphabetize": {
                "order": "asc",
                "caseInsensitive": true
            },
        }],

These are the original import statements:
import { data } from "../../shared/myfile.tokens";
import { data } from "./../../shared/myfile.service";

These are what ESlint modified them to:
import { data } from "./../../shared/myfile.service";
import { data } from "../../shared/myfile.tokens";

But why is this happening? ESLint is supposed to arrange them in ascending order and ".." comes before "./" in the charset?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I solved this problem my explicitly stating the parent and sibling groups in my ESLint Config file.
From this:
"groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal"],
to this:
"groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal", "parent","sibling"],
